# WPF Ribbon ApplicationMenu open and close event

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I'm using the WPF Ribbon Application Menu:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11877

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx

- How can I close the Application (File) Menu programmatically?
- How can I detect if the user opens the Application Menu? I didn't found an appropriated event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`IsDropDownOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonmenubutton.isdropdownopen(v=vs.110).aspx) property and related event(s).
XAML (this is for .NET 4.5+, but for 4.0 it will be almost the same, the difference will be in namespace prefix):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Ribbon>
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu x:Name="Menu" DropDownOpened="RibbonApplicationMenu_DropDownOpened">
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Foo"/>
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Bar"/>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    </Ribbon>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RibbonApplicationMenu_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // user has opened menu
        Debug.WriteLine("Menu opened.");
        // let's close it from code
        Menu.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Also, you may want to disable entire menu. This can be done using `IsEnabled` property.